# Enabled/Disabled JButton associated with some method

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'd like to have `JButton` in some class that is enabled/disabled when some method returns `true`/`false` (method return component of class - type `boolean`)

I don't know how to do that. Should I write instruction `while(true) { ... }` and check what method returns for example 1 per second? Is it a good idea?

Please help

Comment: JButton.setEnabled(foo()); Where foo() is your method that returns true/false. Or inside foo() before the return true/false JButton.setEnabled(true/false);

Comment: `while(true) { ... }` is a very bad idea (that actually won't work).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From Java Se 7 Doc,

```
Methods inherited from class javax.swing.AbstractButton
```

If you put this code within your method, then whenever it runs, it will enable/disable the button accordingly.

Comment: +1 for that massive picture. Normally people put a link, this is taking it to a whole new level.

Comment: @CPUTerminator Thanks, I went to make it as clear as possible, and figured big pic was the way to go this time.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I write instruction while(true) { ... } and check what method
>   returns for example 1 per second? Is it a good idea?

This is bad idea, it will freeze your application completely!
If you want to check the value of boolean method periodically use the Timer.

However if the boolean method is defined in say Object A and you know when A is modified then you should add the buttons as listener to A so that when A is modified it can trigger a callback in the Button which will evaluate whether the button should be enabled or disabled now.

Answer (score 0):

```
final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        btnNewButton.setEnabled(buttonState());
    }
});

boolean buttonState() {
    return false;
}
```